# Compare file compression methods by sending to /dev/null

Tags: compression, null

I'd like to compare the time to completion for compression algorithms and parameters. I'm confident that the inputs will be set up properly. In order to save space and avoid some variability my thought is to just send output to `/dev/null`. What are downsides in this situation?

Comment: then yes just use `time comand > /dev/null`  if results are just time based. like ` time tar cvf /dev/null Pictures/png/` here goes : ` Pictures/png/rcrrcrncrcnz.png

real 0m0.011s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s`

Comment: The downside is that you can't time the uncompression speeds.

Comment: Another downside is that you will not get the size (compression ratio) unless you pipe the output via something that will show the size, for example `dd` (which will also show the time used).